# How to do performance test at a code level - I need to put load on certain UI methods

Tags: jmeter

In my application , there are images we used to upload for a question. I need to conduct a performance test with 1000 users who are going to upload images during their activity.

To conduct this test, I need to call the UI method which was written by developers to get successful results.

Can any one help here to achieve this? if not , please update any other alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to "performance test at a code level" - take a look at [microbenchmarking](https://www.adservio.fr/post/what-is-microbenchmarking) concept in general and the microbenchmarking for the language in which your backend is developed in particular.

It's not clear what do you mean by "UI method", normally JMeter doesn't interact with "UI", it works on [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) level. If "UI method" is associated with sending a network request - you can simulate the request using JMeter and it will measure the time taken. Image upload by 1000 users can also be simulated using JMeter.

If your application is a web application (or uses HTTP protocol) you can even record your test scenario using JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)